# html tag does not exist in view page-source

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the link of pdf and the links of download from the visuals table in
url= https://store.danfoss.com//en/Climate-Solutions-for-cooling/Sensors-and-transmitters/Sensors/Temperature-sensors/Temperature-sensor%2C-ETN%2C-1-50-m/p/077F8726

my problem is the HTML tags do not exist in view-source so I cannot scrape them.
here is my code:

```
table=soup.find('table',attrs={'class':'table visual-table sort-table dynamic-table'})
if(table):
    rows = table.find_all('li')
    for row in rows:
        a=row.find_all('a',href=True)
        for i in a:
            print('img: ',i['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the HTML content or the page source does not contain your target tag is because of it's actually not there when you first hit the URL and the page gets loaded.

To load the desired data/table, you need to scroll down to the bottom of the page since the target tag lies at the bottom. This involves the JavaScript operation to perform the scrolling and the "requests" library does not support it.

you can instead use selenium. Here is the solution:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://store.danfoss.com//en/Climate-Solutions-for-cooling/Sensors-and-transmitters/Sensors/Temperature-sensors/Temperature-sensor%2C-ETN%2C-1-50-m/p/077F8726")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table visual-table sort-table dynamic-table'})
if table:
    rows = table.find_all('li')
    for row in rows:
        a = row.find_all('a', href=True)
        for i in a:
            print('img: ', i['href'])
```

output:

```
img:  //assets.danfoss.com/photos/latest/124173/ID107321600491-0101.tif
img:  //assets.danfoss.com/photos/latest/116310/ID293850993907-0101.tif
img:  //assets.danfoss.com/drawings/latest/26540/ID296341415372-0101.tif
img:  //assets.danfoss.com/drawings/latest/15778/ID046786495748-0101.jpg
img:  //assets.danfoss.com/drawings/latest/15783/ID046786495746-0101.eps
img:  //assets.danfoss.com/drawings/latest/15784/ID046786495741-0101.jpg
img:  //assets.danfoss.com/drawings/latest/15785/ID046786495739-0101.eps
```

Hope, it answers your question.